# How can I redirect MVC5 RedirectResult () to a full page in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

In my ASP.NET MVC5 page I have an individual login feature with timeout. This works fine, once the timeout has expired, the login page opens at the next action and then it goes on.
There is only one layout problem. If I click on a logged-out user in a PartialView, the login page is rendered in this PartialView and not on the whole page.
Code for authentication:

```
        public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Result == null || filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Session["PlantId"] = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["PlantId"];
            filterContext.HttpContext.Session["ShowOnlyEnabledRecipes"] = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["ShowOnlyEnabledRecipes"];
             filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/UserLogin/Login");
        }
    }
```

And Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        Initialize();
         ...
        return View(loginModel);
            }
```

How can I ensure that the login form always occupies an entire page? Also, if it is called by clicking on a PartialView?

Answer (score -1):

Do redirect in the PartialView(the controller for PartialView), the result only render in the area, if you want to direct to another page(url changed), you need to add below code in the controller. You will have advanced info from Ref link.

P.S. ActionFilter cannot return JavaScript, please put in the normal controller.

Ref: http://geekswithblogs.net/DougLampe/archive/2011/08/05/redirecting-from-a-partial-view-the-right-way-in-asp.net.aspx

```
string virtualPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;
string returnUrl = virtualPath + "/UserLogin/Login";
return JavaScript( string .Format( "document.location = '{0}';" , returnUrl));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it